# How do I search and replace nodes Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML document as a string. I parsed it using Nokogiri:

```
doc_str = <<-mydoc
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit foo.</p>
  <h2>Consectetur adipisicing bar</h2>
  <p>Foo do <a href="/c-foo.aspx" class = "foo" title="Foo bar.">foofoo foo</a>.</p>
mydoc

doc = Nokogiri::HTML doc_str
```

I want to replace `"foo"` / `"Foo"` by `"Bar"` / `"bar"` in all visible texts:

```
desired = <<-mydoc
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit bar.</p>
  <h2>Consectetur adipisicing bar</h2>
  <p>Bar do <a href="/c-foo.aspx" class = "foo" title="Bar bar.">foofoo bar</a>.</p>
mydoc
```

How do I do that?

I tried to read the [Nokogiri tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html), which describes `Nokogiri::HTML::Document#at_css`. Using Ruby 2.0, and the latest Nokogiri, `doc.at_css 'h1'` returns `nil`, so `h1.content = "something"` is not even possible.

Even if it worked, it would be only a first step towards solving my find and replace problem.

Answer (score 3):

`doc.at_css 'h1'` returns `nil` because there are no `h1` elements in your HTML. `doc.at_css 'h2'` correctly returns the `Nokogiri::XML::Element` object for the `h2` element.

CSS selectors are unable to select text nodes and are a poor tool for this sort of thing. XPath will do all that CSS does and much more besides. A text node anywhere beneath the root of the document is simply `//text()`.

**Edit** I've just noticed that you seem to want the content of attributes changing in the same way. `@*` matches any attribute, so the XPath expression becomes `//@* | //text()`. Although I'm not clear about this as `href="/c-foo.aspx"` and `class="foo"` remain unchanged but `title="Foo bar."` becomes `title="bar bar."`. I'm sure you can sort this out for yourself.

You need to find all the text nodes using XPath and then use `content` to fetch the text value of each node. Modify it as you wish and use `content=` to replace it.

This program demonstrates. The `to_html` method wraps the data in the tags necessary to make it valid HTML.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc_str = <<-HTML
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit foo.</p>
  <h2>Consectetur adipisicing bar</h2>
  <p>Foo do <a href="/c-foo.aspx" class = "foo" title="Foo bar.">foofoo foo</a>.</p>
HTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(doc_str)

doc.xpath('//@*', '//text()').each do |node|
  node.content = node.content.gsub(/\bfoo\b/, 'bar').gsub(/\bFoo\b/, 'Bar')
end

puts doc.to_html
```

**output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit bar.</p>
  <h2>Consectetur adipisicing bar</h2>
  <p>Bar do <a href="/c-bar.aspx" class="bar" title="Bar bar.">foofoo bar</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me so much, but please note that your example is not completely correct, as it also replaced `class="foo"` into `class="bar"`, which it shouldn't, because it is not a visible text. On the contrary, @pguardiario 's `#traverse` example does not suffer `class="bar"` problem, he missed `\b` wrapping around `foo` and `Foo`. Could you please tell me more about the argument of the `#xpath` method? I mean that `'//@* | //text()'`. What the heaven does it mean?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: So the difference between the attributes in your question is intentional? It isn't at all clear. You would have to enumerate the names of the attributes that you wanted processing to get this correct. The XPath terms `text()` and `@*` I have already explained. `//` means "descendant", and when it's at the start of the expression it means "descendant of the root", i.e. anywhere in the document. The pipe `|` is "union" so complete expression selects all attribute nodes and all text nodes anywhere. [Look here for the specification of XPath 1.0.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Comment: Change `@*` to `@title` and I think you'll have nailed it.

Comment: @MarkThomas: Well yes I could throw that in, but it would make it work only with *this* example. If a change is to be made then we need a list of the names of *all* attributes that are to be transformed.

Comment: Yes, the OP will need to define a list of visible attributes. There's no automatic way to do it. But replacing *all* attributes is incorrect.